# Is there a way to make QTabWidgets auto-hide the tab bar if only one tab is visible (but there are multiple tabs)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I have a [`QTabWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html) instance called `tabWidget`, and it has two `QTableWidget` children.

I've called [`setTabBarAutoHide(true)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#tabBarAutoHide-prop) on the `QTabWidget`, and I've also called [`setTabVisible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#setTabVisible) with `false` as a parameter for the second tab.

I expected `setTabBarAutoHide(true)` to mean that the tab bar will not be displayed since there is only one visible tab. However, this is not the case - there's only one visible tab and the bar is not hidden.

If I never add the second tab, the behavior is as expected - the tab bar stays hidden.

Here is a rough idea of what my code looks like:

```cpp
QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
tabWidget->setTabBarAutoHide(true);

QTableWidget* firstTab = new QTableWidget();
tabWidget->addTab(firstTab, "First Tab");

QTableWidget* secondTab = new QTableWidget();
tabWidget->addTab(secondTab, "Second Tab");
tabWidget->setTabVisible(1, false);
```

Is there a "nice" way to auto-hide the tab bar if only one tab is visible (but multiple tabs exist)? If not, what is the most idiomatic way to get this functionality?

Comment: Just hide the QTabWidget `tabBar()` whenever only one tab is visible. If the QTabWidget `count()` is <= 1, leave it to the default behavior, otherwise use a for loop with that count and check for `isTabVisible()`: if the visible count is > 1, break the loop and show it, otherwise hide it.

Comment: I tested it without using `setTabVisible` to hide the second tab and it didn't show a tab bar if only one tab is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt, `setTabBarAutoHide(true)` is indeed supposed to automatically hide the tab bar when there's only **one tab visible**. However, it seems there might be a **conflict** with setting a tab to be invisible using `setTabVisible(false)`.

To achieve the behavior you want, you can use a workaround. Instead of using setTabVisible(false) to hide the second tab, you can remove it from the QTabWidget. Then, when you want to show it again, you can add it back. This way, the setTabBarAutoHide(true) should work as expected.

like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTableWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Create the QTabWidget
    QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
    tabWidget->setTabBarAutoHide(true);

    // Create the first tab and add it to the tab widget
    QTableWidget* firstTab = new QTableWidget();
    tabWidget->addTab(firstTab, "First Tab");

    // Create the second tab and add it to the tab widget
    QTableWidget* secondTab = new QTableWidget();
    tabWidget->addTab(secondTab, "Second Tab");

    // Remove the second tab from the tab widget
    tabWidget->removeTab(1);

    // Show the tab widget
    tabWidget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I started to implement before deciding to ask if there was a better way. I'm not sure which is less ugly, removing and adding tabs dynamically like this or modifying the `QTabWidget tabBar()` to hide if only one tab is visible like the other comment suggested.